# Dynamically import React Components based on input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I want to render different Components based on some checkboxes selection pattern without having to import components that may not be used.

I have an Array which contains the Component names (I used numbers as an example) and I want to import each component based on the values of the array.

I came up with something like this:

```js
import {Suspense} from 'react'


export default function CreationForm() {

 const docs = [1,3,5]

  return (
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        {
          docs.map(val => React.lazy(() => import(`documents/${val}.jsx`)))   
        }
      </Suspense>
  )

}
```

I know this solution does not work but I think it explains what I am trying to do.

I could try using state but the actual "docs array" is an state variable in the real application so it could cause duplicated state.

I did this as a test and worked:

```js
  const A = React.lazy(() => import(`documents/1.jsx`))
  ...
  *** SNIP ***
  ...
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        {
          docs.map((val) => <A/>)   
        }
      </Suspense>
```

But I cannot dynamically import each component like this.

Comment: Why is it important that you don't import Components that aren't used? Are you trying to keep a super low code footprint? That comes with some tough challenges.

Comment: The amount of Components I have to import could vary on the future and I don't see it viable to import them every time I add one.

Comment: Either I don't understand what you're trying to do, or you don't understand what `import` does. Typically your IDE will help in managing your imports. You also don't typically import conditionally (or at all). You might _render_ conditionally, but the imports are static.

Comment: I have my doubts if what I am trying to do is the best solution for the problem I'm facing.

What I'm intending to do is render a new component (that are all different kinds of forms) based on some checkboxes. 
If a particular checkbox is selected it may require to render one form (or maybe more).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you don't need conditional imports, you just want to do conditional rendering. That's waaaaay simpler.

Example:

```
import { FormA } from "./FormA";
import { FormB } from "./FormB";

const MyComponent = ({ which }) => {
    return <>
        {which === "form-a" && <FormA />}
        {which === "form-b" && <FormB />}
    <>;
};
```

Comment: I thought of this as a solution. You think using an object as alternative could be much less efficient or less readable for others?

Comment: Use an object where?

Comment: Instead of using the short-circuit returning the component as: 
```return FORMS[which]
```

Comment: Sure, you could do that. There aren't really any rules on when something should be a Component.